# How read pubdate field using willvincent/feeds plugin?

Tags: laravel-5, rss-reader

I use https://github.com/willvincent/feeds for reading rss and with all field I also need to get pubDate field.
iI did not find a method for it(I looked also in source app/library/AppRssImport.php file ) and I made some debugging, so methods

```
            echo '<pre>$RssItem->data[\'child\']::'.print_r($RssItem->data['child'],true).'</pre>';
            dd($RssItem->data['child']);
```

has next output:

```
$RssItem->data['child']::Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => Man died 'in agony' after stroke amid ambulance delays
                            [attribs] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [xml_base] => 
                            [xml_base_explicit] => 
                            [xml_lang] => 
                        )

                )

            [description] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => Michelle Lane has PTSD and flashbacks of her husband screaming in pain as they went to hospital by car.
                            [attribs] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [xml_base] => 
                            [xml_base_explicit] => 
                            [xml_lang] => 
                        )

                )

            [link] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-nottinghamshire-46795776
                            [attribs] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [xml_base] => 
                            [xml_base_explicit] => 
                            [xml_lang] => 
                        )

                )

            [guid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-nottinghamshire-46795776
                            [attribs] => Array
                                (
                                    [] => Array
                                        (
                                            [isPermaLink] => true
                                        )

                                )

                            [xml_base] => 
                            [xml_base_explicit] => 
                            [xml_lang] => 
                        )

                )

            [pubDate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => Thu, 10 Jan 2019 10:02:22 GMT
                            [attribs] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [xml_base] => 
                            [xml_base_explicit] => 
                            [xml_lang] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/] => Array
        (
            [thumbnail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => 
                            [attribs] => Array
                                (
                                    [] => Array
                                        (
                                            [width] => 1024
                                            [height] => 576
                                            [url] => http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/15CE0/production/_105121398_michelle-tony.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [xml_base] => 
                            [xml_base_explicit] => 
                            [xml_lang] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and  https://imgur.com/a/wTmd9cV
I tried to read value of pubDate field, but failed. This structure was rather strange for me...
Which is right decision ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_date()` method to grab the value of `pubDate`?

https://github.com/willvincent/feeds this plugin is only a wrapper around SimplePie php extension. You can look into SimplePie documentation for all other available methods. http://simplepie.org/api/class-SimplePie_Item.html.

A usable code might be like this. I used laravel, so the first line of grabbing the feed might be different.

```
$feed = Feeds::make('https://www.example.com/feed/');
$items = $feed->get_items();

foreach( $items as $key => $item ) {
    $title = $item->get_title();
    $guid = $item->get_id();
    $pub_date = $item->get_date();
}
```